# Column in Jtable doesn't show

Tags: javascript, symfony, datagrid, jtable

I created a Datagrid with JTable, this is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: '{{ path("person_list") }}',
                createAction: '',
                updateAction: '',
                deleteAction: ''
            },
            fields: {
                PersonId: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                Age: {
                    title: 'Age',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                PaysId: {
                    title: 'Country',
                    width: '30%'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code works fine, it displays all information.

```
____________________________
Name      |  Age    | Country
----------------------------
Mohssine  | 22      | France
Saad      | 10      | USA
____________________________
```

After I added this code :

```
options: '{{ path("get_countries") }}',
```

to display a Combobox for the user when he want to change or create a new record, here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: '{{ path("person_list") }}',
                createAction: '',
                updateAction: '',
                deleteAction: ''
            },
            fields: {
                PersonId: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                Age: {
                    title: 'Age',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                PaysId: {
                    title: 'Country',
                    options: '{{ path("get_countries") }}',
                    width: '30%'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP code: A function that return a list of countries

```
public function getCountriesAction()
    {
        $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('select country as DisplayText,id as value from countries');
        $stmt->execute();
        $countries = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['Options'] = $countries;
        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' =>  new JsonEncoder()));
        $content = $serializer->encode($jTableResult, 'json');
        return new Response($content);
    }
```

When I display my datagrid all the information is there, except the column that I added in the code, it is displayed without information.

```
____________________________
Name      |  Age    | Country
----------------------------
Mohssine  | 22      | 
Saad      | 10      | 
____________________________
```

A solution please and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your function **getCountriesAction** :

```
public function getregionsAction()
    {
        $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('select country,id from countries');
        $stmt->execute();
        $countries= $stmt->fetchAll();



        foreach ($countries=  as $key => $value) {

            $eil = array();
            $eil["DisplayText"] = $countries[$key]['country'];
            $eil["Value"] = $countries[$key]['id'];
            $rows[] = $eil;  
        }

        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['Options'] = $rows;

        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
        $content = $serializer->encode($jTableResult, 'json');
        return new Response($content);
    }
```

please check this : https://gist.github.com/cristic84/5883136

I hope this solution will help you.